# Anyway to add an HTTP status code on ActiveRecord validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using locale to configure error messages coming from my Rails API server, was wondering if there is anyway to also attach HTTP status codes?

For instance:

say I have a model:

email.rb

```
class Email < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :email_address
  validates :email_address, allow_blank: true, format: { with: URI::MailTo::EMAIL_REGEXP }, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false }
end
```

I have the config set up like so:

en.yml

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      email:
        email_address: Email address
    errors:
      messages:
        record_invalid: "%{errors}"
        # I want to do something like this
        blank:
          message: is required.
          status_code: 422
        taken:
          message: is already taken.
          status_code: 409
```

Programmatically is fine too, I just want to return the appropriate HTTP status code, 422, 409, 404, 401 etc. when applicable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, **which I don't recommend**

You'll need to write some extra code, the default behavior is 422, to change it, you can add code that asks what errors does the model has a respond accordingly, or figure out a way to monkey patch the built in rails code that responds with 422.

see [relevant rails code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/41bbd7cd0e4e950ea5a366f78b26b32ed6bd0644/activerecord/lib/active_record/railtie.rb) line 25

Anyway it's a bit of code smell (what you are currently trying to achieve), the model should not be aware of anything related to HTTP, so maybe the translation isn't the proper place for status codes (it wouldn't change if you are on another human spoken language)

Comment: I think, raising a custom error for the invalid object and adding an appropriate HTTP handler for the error might just allow them to avoid exposing HTTP related details to the model. WDYT?

Comment: You make a good point, however there are far more HTTP error codes than those provided. How do you suggest I then leverage that to add more HTTP codes?

Comment: EDIT to above: I also want to log these errors, so I can't really just let Rails handle the response when it catches an exception.

Comment: Raise you own errors, catch them and set the response code